# Python lists find value by key

Tags: python

The function I call from the main program is

```
elif retrieve_user(user_login):
        print("Hello " + user_login + ", welcome!\n")
```

I use the function `util.csv_to_dict('user.csv')` and I want to find the name of users they inclound in user.csv file:

```
news_items = util.csv_to_dict('users.csv')
print("The list of contacts ie: \n", news_items)
for n in news_items:
    if n==username:
        print('O user found!!!!')
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Its not work and I don't know the reason. Pls help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and use proper formatting

Comment: also include some sample lines from `users.csv` including the header (if any)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should look more like:

```
news_items = util.csv_to_dict('users.csv')
print("The list of contacts ie: \n", news_items)
for n in news_items:
    if n==username:
        print('O user found!!!!')
        return True
return False
```

That way, it's only after looping on all keys, if the user wasn't found you return `False` value. In your original code, only the first iteration of the `for` loop is completed and you will return value `True` only if it matches the first one.

Don't hesitate if you need more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are utilizing dictionary in your code. Normally when dealing with dictionaries, I use exception handling to "increase efficiency" of my code. [*"Better to ask forgiveness than permission"*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/)

Alternative solution:

```
def check_user(username):
    news_items = util.csv_to_dict('users.csv')
    print("The list of contacts ie: \n", news_items)
    try:
        if news_items[username]:
            print('O user found!!!!')
            return True
    except:
        return False
```